# VBScript's Shell Command Will Not Execute Unless An Output File Is Specified

Tags: cmd, vbscript, command-prompt

I'm trying to run a shell command for google speech recognition. I'm able to run the command **only** if I provide an output file to the command string.

As you can see my test code sample below, I would attach the ">*outputFile*" if one is provided and also coded in a timeout loop to abort the process after a set time limit.

```
strCommand = "cmd /c ipconfig /all"
If outputFile <> "" Then
    strCommand = strCommand & " > """ & outputFile & """"
End If
Set wshShellExec = wshShell.Exec(strCommand)
expiration = DateAdd("s", 600, Now)
Do While wshShellExec.Status = WshRunning And Now < expiration
    WScript.Sleep 5000
Loop 
Select Case wshShellExec.Status
    Case WshRunning
        wshShellExec.Terminate
        TestFunction = "{""error"": ""TestFunction Command Timed Out""}"
    Case WshFinished
        TestFunction =  WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
    Case WshFailed
        TestFunction = wshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
End Select
```

If I leave `outputFile` empty and try to expect the output to be returned from the function, all it does is sit still for 5 minutes before timing out and sending me my error message.
Why does it need an output file to run?
If I run the command line manually on a Command Prompt, it runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output buffers have limited capacity. If your command writes too much text to stdout the buffer will fill up and block the command from writing more until you clear the buffer (e.g. by reading from it). `ReadAll` can't be used for that, though, because that method will only return *after* the command has finished and block otherwise, thus creating a deadlock.

Your best option is to redirect output to one or more (temp) files, and read the output from those files after the command has finished.

```vb
outfile = "C:\out.txt"
errfile = "C:\err.txt"

cmd = "cmd /c ipconfig /all >""" & outfile & """ 2>""" & errfile & """"

timeout = DateAdd("s", 600, Now)

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ex = sh.Exec(cmd)
Do While ex.Status = WshRunning And Now < timeout
    WScript.Sleep 200
Loop

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outtxt = fso.OpenTextFile(outfile).ReadAll
errtxt = fso.OpenTextFile(errfile).ReadAll
```

If you don't want to do that for some reason you must read from `StdOut` repeatedly.

```vb
outtxt = ""
errtxt = ""

cmd = "ipconfig /all"

timeout = DateAdd("s", 600, Now)

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ex = sh.Exec(cmd)
Do While ex.Status = WshRunning And Now < timeout
    WScript.Sleep 200
    outtxt = outtxt & ex.StdOut.ReadLine & vbNewLine
Loop
```

Note that you may also need to read from `StdErr`, because that buffer might fill up too if there is too much error output. However, reading *both* buffers might create *another* deadlock, because IIRC `ReadLine` blocks until it can read a full line, so if the script might hang waiting for error output that never appears. You might be able to work around that by using `Read` instead of `ReadLine`, but it'll still be very fragile.

So, again, your best option is to redirect command output to files and read those files after the command terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Once the `wshShellExec` is terminated in the `WshRunning` case, instead of assigning the error message, the output should be assigned.

```
Select Case wshShellExec.Status
Case WshRunning
    wshShellExec.Terminate
    TestFunction = "Terminated: " & vbcrlf & WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll() 
Case WshFinished
    TestFunction =  "Finished: " & vbcrlf & WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
Case WshFailed
    TestFunction = wshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
End Select
```