# Does cmd.exe write to stdout/stderr?

Tags: windows, cmd, vbscript, stdout, command-prompt

This is a weird question based on bad VBScript behavior that I am trying to work around. Please bear with me and thank you in advance.

In VBScript, you can do the following to start a task:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
Do While WshShellExec.Status <> WshFinished
    WScript.Sleep(1000)
Loop
```

However, there is a bug where, if the command/task started by the WshShell.Exec call writes >=4kb to either StdOut or StdErr, WshShellExec.Status will *never* be equal to WshFinished (1). I assume this is because there is no space in a buffer the system uses for stdout/stderr, so the initiated task hangs on the next write to stdout/stderr once it writes enough bytes to the buffer(s).

Depending on the program running, you may be able to do something like the following to get around it:

```
Set wshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(cmd)
Set objStdOut = wshShellExec.StdOut
Set objStdErr = wshShellExec.StdErr

Do Until objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
    standardout = standardout & objStdOut.ReadLine & vbCrlf
Loop

Do Until objStdErr.AtEndOfStream
    errtext = errtext & objStdErr.ReadLine & vbCrlf
Loop
```

However, this does not always work. If the running program writes 4kb to stderr before writing anything to stdout, this code hangs on the evaluation of objStdOut.AtEndOfStream or on objStdOut.ReadLine (note, you cannot use objStdOut.ReadAll because that will also block forever).

So, I've come up with the following solution that seems to work:

```
strCommand = "c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C StdOutTester.exe > " & rsltTextFile & " 2>&1 || call echo %^errorLevel% > " & rsltErrCodeFile

Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

Do While WshShellExec.Status <> WshFinished 
    Wscript.Sleep(1000)
    secCount = secCount+1
    If secCount >= 10 Then 'kill children
        If KillTaskChildren(WshShellExec.ProcessID) <> 0 Then
            WScript.Echo "WMI Terminate Failed. Killing CMD..."
            WshShellExec.Terminate
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

What this does is run the actual task in another cmd window and redirect both stdout/stderr into a file (and also the error code if applicable). Because I'm running the command in another cmd window, stdout and stderr are decoupled from the WshShellExec object. This also allows me to kill the running task for a timeout (the real one, i.e. not the cmd window but the actual task, by using WMI).

So, my question becomes this:

Since I am running another cmd.exe window, it is possible that cmd prompt itself runs into the same issue if it writes enough data into stdout/stderr (in which case, my timeout logic should kill it)? Does it ever actually write anything into stdout/stderr? What about if I use the /Q option?

Comment: Redirection is writing whatever is being written to a given file descriptor (STDOUT, STDERR, etc.) directly to a file, not a buffer, so the answer to your question is "no". Using `/c` or `/k` doesn't make a difference there, since the parameters only control whether the command prompt closes or keeps running after the command finishes. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54479746/1630171).

Comment: Isn't the redirection for the stdout/stderr part of the command started by the new cmd.exe (i.e. not cmd.exe itself) though? Also, whoops! I meant /Q, not /K.

Comment: Output redirection is a feature provided by CMD. Running `cmd /c some.exe > output.txt` works. Running just `some.exe > output.txt` does not.

Comment: Echoing does not have anything to do with redirection. It just controls whether CMD will or won't display the command being run on top of the command output. Setting or omitting `/q` does the same as using `echo off` or `echo on` respectively.

Comment: @AngsarWiechers why is cmd able to set the stdout of cmd.exe to the file but not some.exe, it seems like it easily could

Comment: @AngsarWiechers I just tested it on my windows 7, works fine without cmd /c, as I would have thought. Although there is some evidence of it not working https://superuser.com/questions/917323/cannot-redirect-exe-output-to-file#comment1764357_917323 but I can't imagine why

Comment: It works if cmd /c does not open a new cmd.exe, but if it does (i.e. using admin cmd.exe) then it doesn't work and still displays to the console screen buffer in the new window, which i suppose makes sense -- the cmd.exe always has the screen buffer as stdout and can't be changed. You have to run the redirection as a command `admin /k "\Users\lewis\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1 > \Users\lewis\Desktop\output3.txt"` works but without the quotation marks it does not because you cant redirect cmd.exe, but you can redirect ConsoleApplication1.exe from within the new console